# reticulate R package error in fuzzywuzzy module

Tags: r, linux, artificial-intelligence, fuzzywuzzy, reticulate

i have a problem with reticulate package in R

```
library(reticulate)

fuz  <- import("fuzzywuzzy")

print(fuz$ratio("ello", "hello"))
```

i have tried to use fuzzywuzzy(python module) in R but got an error:

```
Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) :                                    
   AttributeError: module 'fuzzywuzzy' has no attribute 'ratio'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that helped

```
library(fuzzywuzzyR)

fuz  <- FuzzMatcher$new()

fuz$Ratio("ello", "hello")
```